# customising Authorize mvc3 error 

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to customize the authorize in mvc 3. In the home controller i am setting role to be...

```
Session["role"] = "Admin";
```

I am getting the error at

```
SiteRoles role = (SiteRoles)httpContext.Session["role"];
```

saying Specified cast is not valid.

I dont have a clue what is happening.

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (httpContext == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

    string[] users = Users.Split(',');

    if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return false;

    string role = (string)httpContext.Session["role"]; 

    if (Roles != 0 && ((Roles & role) != role))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: also i am following example at...http://mvchosting.asphostcentral.com/post/ASPNET-MVC-Hosting-Working-with-Custom-Authorisation-in-ASPNET-MVC-Framework.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a string inside the session, so you should use a string when reading back:

```
string role = (string)httpContext.Session["role"];
```

Or if you wanted to set some custom type:

```
Session["role"] = SiteRoles.Admin;
```

and then you will be able to:

```
SiteRoles role = (SiteRoles)httpContext.Session["role"];
```

Comment: @Beginner, `SiteRoles` seems to be an enum which is baked by an integer => you are already setting an integer inside the session when writing `Session["role"] = SiteRoles.Admin;`. But you could also write `Session["role"] = 1;`